# Anaconda wouldn't start. OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, anaconda

Anaconda Navigator wouldn't start. So I opened Anaconda Prompt and type 'conda info' and some other conda commands. But most of the time, I get " OSError: [Error 9] Bad file descriptor " I couldn't find this issue anywhere related with Anaconda. What might cause this issue and how can I fix this?

Error is as below:

(base) C:\Users\soe>conda info

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1003, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 304, in execute
    info_dict = get_info_dict(args.system)
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 173, in get_info_dict
    user_agent=context.user_agent,
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
    cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 619, in user_agent
    builder = ["conda/%s requests/%s" % (CONDA_VERSION, self.requests_version)]
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\_vendor\auxlib\decorators.py", line 268, in new_fget
    cache[inner_attname] = func(self)
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\base\context.py", line 630, in requests_version
    from requests import __version__ as REQUESTS_VERSION
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ._internal_utils import to_native_string
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\_internal_utils.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .compat import is_py2, builtin_str, str
  File "C:\Users\soe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 60, in <module>
    from http.cookies import Morsel
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 724, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 859, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 917, in get_data
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k38SG.jpg)

Comment: Please consider adding the traceback to your question.

Comment: I've added traceback.

Comment: Reinstallation is not a bad option

Comment: I _already_ did but that didn't solve the issue. :(

Comment: I'm have this same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It was on my Windows PC. Now I'm on Ubuntu and using python without anaconda. The error is still there on my Windows PC.